# Why some microcontrollers have so high price/performance ratio?

Tags: microcontroller, cost

PIC16F877A is $6.72 / 1 pc,     $4.68 / 100 pcs from [Digi-Key](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/PIC16F877A-I%2FP/PIC16F877A-I%2FP-ND/446143).

ATMEGA328P is $4.98 / 1 pc,     $2.77 / 100 pcs from [Digi-Key](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/ATMEGA328P-PU/ATMEGA328P-PU-ND/1914589).

LPC1113FBD48 is $2.24 / 1pc,    $1.64 / 100 pcs from [Digi-Key](http://parts.digikey.com/1/parts/1802327-ic-mcu-32bit-24kb-flash-48lqfp-lpc1113fbd48-301-1.html)

I know that my compare is not fair in the case of manufacturer, packaging.. However, by the means of functions and capability, isn't $4.68 too much for PIC16F877A, or $2.77 for ATMEGA328?

Why are these parts so expensive? Do you think that they are going to be  cheaper?

*Pardon me if it is a silly and/or off-topic question.*

Comment: This is potentially a very subjective question.  Remember that answers should cite references and sources! Please help improve answers by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I don't get it, could you be more open?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - None of the people who will answer this question have inside information or have set the prices for these controllers.  Therefore, answers will describe the reality of the situation as perceived rather than as independent of any individual's mind; this is the definition of subjective.  Stack Exchange sites are not forums which welcome subjective discussion, see the [good subjective, bad subjective blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information.

Comment: @KevinVermeer thank you for more information, and I am sorry. I can delete my post if it will be better.

Comment: Nope, it's OK - It's not a purely subjective question; Olin and Kellenjb were able to answer it objectively with information on what costs money on microcontrollers.  A couple others gave subjective answers, which were downvoted and had to be deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, DigiKey single quantity prices are no indication of anything useful.  If you want to make relative price comparisons between PICs, go to the Microchip Direct web site and see what they are actually selling for in at least 100 quantity, although 5000 quantity will be a better guide.

Second, the 16F877A is a old part.  It is probably using a older silicon process with larger feature size, and therefore its die is larger than newer parts even when they have more stuff on them.  Silicon chip prices are mostly about die size, and a little bit about volume.  I suspect the old 16F877A is large and low volume.

This is a normal thing in the semiconductor business.  As feature sizes shrink with new fab technology, newer parts become more capable *and* cheaper.  Sometimes if the manufacturer thinks the part would be competative at the new smaller feature size, they redesign it for that process in what's called a "die shrink".  However, other technology is usually advancing with microcontrollers so fast that the effort to invest in a die shrink is better spent designing a new part.

At least Microchip understands that it's a pain to redesign a old product because parts went obsolete.  They have been very good about making old parts available, but of course as the volumes go down it's understandable the price goes up.  You can still buy a 16F84, for example, but it will cost more and do less than newer parts.  At least it's still available.  Other manufacturers just stop production and then you're screwed.

Comment: Yes, they are priced in 5K volume in Microchip's site. So the thing to do is constantly watching for new products and using them as much as I can, right? I guess programming a PIC18F13K50 will not be hard for someone that has some experience on 16F887 or 16F84?

Comment: @abdullah: The thing to do is a parametric search whenever you start a new project.  There are so many different parts, even within one company like Microchip, that  it's impossible to have more than a general idea of what is available.  Let the parametric search tell you which parts have the mix of peripherals, memory, speed, and whatever you are looking for, then drill down for more details until you find the best match.  There are some differences between the 8 bit PIC families, but moving between them is still pretty easy once you are familiar with the issues.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the price/performance of a PIC16C73/JW which has had one of its inputs accidentally tied to AC120 through a 1K resistor (blowing the resistor off the board) will probably be better than that of a newer part which has been similarly treated (note: been there, done that; the PIC, which was one of the windowed parts used for development, continued to work just fine after the resistor was replaced).  While I wouldn't recommend treating any part in such fashion, the extra cost of those older parts does buy some "beefiness" which newer parts often lack.

Answer (score 7):

Typically what drives the price of microcontrollers is their amount a memory (including all memory, whether is be system or storage) and their extra features. The speed of the microcontrollers doesn't tend to follow the price as closely.

The reasons for this is that there is a (relatively) large cost to physically place the memory and any extra features on the chip. Extra features might include things like PWM, ADC, DAC, or it might even be things like extra hardware to perform larger divides or multiplies faster. There can even be a monetary value on having low power.

All of these extra features makes it hard to compare side by side between manufactures. So throwing out 3 seemingly random chips and showing how the price/performance ratio doesn't match up, doesn't have much value. What is best to do is when you have a product that you are developing, you create specs for exactly what it is that you are needing to do. Generally you want to get slightly more then what you actually think you need. Then you go out to all of the different manufactures and find a few ICs from each manufacture that will meet your specifications. From there you just use logic to determine what series is the cheapest or best for your situation.

You will find that certain manufacture have certain realms that they really do well in while others just can't seem to get their price down. But then for another area another manufacture might be way cheaper. This is the biggest reason why you should learn to be able to use any platform.

Note: In the hobbyist world, no one likes to be switching between platforms because of the extra cost associated with new programmers, new dev boards, new compilers, etc. So most people just pick one and go with it. There are plenty of "general purpose" microcontrollers out there that seem to be able to do everything. These of course will be more expensive, but it is something you just have to deal with.

Another Note: Typically companies work in one particular field, whether it be audio, low power sensor networks, etc. Like I mentioned before, generally manufactures have a certain realm that they do well in. Since companies typically work in on particular field, they are able to go with a single manufacture that does well in that area.

Comment: These are good analyses on the subject, however, I guess you misunderstood me. My choice of three random microcontrollers doesn't make sense, but I was asking about general, and I was asking about technology wise old parts being expensive. Nevertheless, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: It would have made more sense to show different parts from the same manufacture if that is what you were trying to get at.

Comment: Nope, my question was not manufacturer specific.